# Want to test that a parameter value is null in querystring

Tags: java

I am using a servlet to do a range of things.

If a particular parameter "t" does not exist I want to do certain types of processing, if it does I want to do different things.

I am trying to test the parameter t (which I save as a String called editType), using the following condition:

```
String editType = request.getParameter("t");
if(!editType.isEmpty()||!(editType==null)){
    //processing here
}
```

How do I do this test properly, because I am getting the problem of a nullpointerexception, because my code always seems to expect a value for "t" I need to be able to create a condition which doesn't expect t (allows it to be null), and do processing in that.

Comment: I removed servlet tag because you don't have problem with Servlet API in particular nor did you receive an exception of the `javax.servlet` package. RuntimeExceptions are just "developer errors" and thus basic Java.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to re-order your comparison a bit, in particular to check for `null` first:

```
String editType = request.getParameter("t");
if(editType!=null && !editType.isEmpty()){
    //processing here
}
```

The problem you are having is that Java is trying to call the `isEmpty()` method on a `null` object, which is why you need to check for `null` first.

Java uses [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), meaning it will check your conditions from left to right, and as soon as it finds one that would let it decide the result of the entire condition, it will stop evaluating. So if `editType` ends up being null, Java will stop evaluating the entire `if` statement and won't try to call `isEmpty()` (which would result in a [`NullPointerException`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)).

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I see you tagged `nullpointerexception` so I make a guess. You should test for null first, then emptiness after:

```
if (editType != null || !editType.isEmpty()) {
    //processing here
}
```

However, this will evaluate to true if `editType` is an empty string. To get the correct result, you should use AND (&&) instead of OR (||), like this:

```
if (editType != null && !editType.isEmpty()){
    //processing here
}
```

Comment: Your first snippet will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

You should change this to

```
String editType = request.getParameter("t");
if(editType != null && !editType.isEmpty()){
    //processing here
}
```

It's useful to have some StringUtil class that offers an ifEmpty() method as this is quite common:

```
public static final class StringUtil {
    private StringUtil() {
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty(String s) {
        return s != null && !s.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Than change you're code to

```
String editType = request.getParameter("t");
if(!StringUtil.isEmpty(editType)){
    //processing here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String editType = request.getParameter("t");
if(!(editType == null || editType.isEmpty())){
   //processing here
}
```

To some people this reads better.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a problem running this code.

It's better this way:

```
String editType = request.getParameter("t");
if(editType!=null&&!editType.isEmpty()){
    //processing here
}
```

null test has to be in the front to avoid the method invocation on null.

Comment: Need to replace `||` with `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the conditions in your if statement are evaluated from left to right.  So the first thing it checks is editType.isEmpty() and if editType is null you will have a null pointer exception.  So the first part of your if should be editType != null (preferred to !(editType == null)).